# Azure Gated Check-In Multiple Synchronous phases for organization

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

There has to be a way to do this I would think, but I do not like having all of my tasks in the same phase. I would like to split it up to where one phase sets everything up (npm install, etc), the next phase runs the unit tests, the next phase builds the app, and the next phase deploys the app.

Is this possible in Azure Devops Pipeline to do this? I currently keep receiving an error going "You cannot have multiple jobs when running gated check-ins", but I'm hoping there is maybe a setting that I am over looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Keep receiving an error going "You cannot have multiple jobs when
>   running gated check-ins"

In fact, this error message has display the limitation for **Gate check-in** in Azure Devops: the azure devops does not support to use Multi-AgentJobs and the Gated check-in together. Thus, there's no such setting can for you to configure and use.

As our designed logic which has been hardcoded into the definition, we only allow one agent to run one single build. This means when you use Gated check-in, you could not apply multi agent-jobs, even could not run single agent job in parallel.

See this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/223724/gated-check-in-no-longer-works-with-builds-that-ha.html) which raised on our official form.

Recently, we received the similar feature suggestion request: [We need use Multi-agent and Gated check-in together.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/642433/we-need-use-multi-agent-and-gated-check-in-togethe.html) You can vote and comment there to advance the priority of this suggestion ticket. And then it could be considered into the develop plan by our Product Manager as soon as possible.